# Invalid Argument Error Keras

Tags: python, keras

I was trying to make a neural network model for binary classification task. The model is like this

```
LEARNING_RATE_INIT = 0.001
LEARNING_RATE_END = 0.0001
BATCH_SIZE = 20000
EPOCHS = 2

EMBEDDING_N = 50
DENSE_N = 1024

SPATIAL_DROPOUT_1D = 0.2
DROPOUT_1 = 0.2
DROPOUT_2 = 0.2

in_machine = Input(shape=[1], name='machine')
emb_machine = Embedding(max_machine, EMBEDDING_N)(in_machine)

in_windspeed = Input(shape=[1], name='windspeed')
emb_windspeed = Embedding(max_windspeed, EMBEDDING_N)(in_windspeed)

in_activepower = Input(shape=[1], name='activepower')
emb_activepower = Embedding(max_activepower, EMBEDDING_N)(in_activepower)

in_pitchangle = Input(shape=[1], name='pitchangle')
emb_pitchangle = Embedding(max_pitchangle, EMBEDDING_N)(in_pitchangle)

in_genspeed = Input(shape=[1], name='genspeed')
emb_genspeed = Embedding(max_genspeed, EMBEDDING_N)(in_genspeed)

in_temp = Input(shape=[1], name='temp')
emb_temp = Embedding(max_temp, EMBEDDING_N)(in_temp)

in_turbine = Input(shape=[1], name='turbine')
emb_turbine = Embedding(max_turbine, EMBEDDING_N)(in_turbine)


print('Create RNN Layers...')

fe = concatenate([
    (emb_machine), 
    (emb_windspeed), 
    (emb_activepower), 
    (emb_pitchangle), 
    (emb_genspeed), 
    (emb_temp), 
    (emb_turbine)
])

s_dout = SpatialDropout1D(SPATIAL_DROPOUT_1D)(fe)
x = Flatten()(s_dout)

x = Dropout(0.2)(Dense(1024,activation='relu')(x))
x = Dropout(0.2)(Dense(256,activation='relu')(x))

outp = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = Model(inputs=[in_machine, in_windspeed, in_activepower, in_pitchangle,
    in_genspeed, in_temp, in_turbine], outputs=outp)

print('Model made')
```

It was compiled like this

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer_adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Model architecture is like shown below

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
machine (InputLayer)            (None, 1)            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
windspeed (InputLayer)          (None, 1)            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activepower (InputLayer)        (None, 1)            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
pitchangle (InputLayer)         (None, 1)            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
genspeed (InputLayer)           (None, 1)            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
temp (InputLayer)               (None, 1)            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
turbine (InputLayer)            (None, 1)            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_48 (Embedding)        (None, 1, 50)        3700        machine[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_49 (Embedding)        (None, 1, 50)        1200        windspeed[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_50 (Embedding)        (None, 1, 50)        108000      activepower[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_51 (Embedding)        (None, 1, 50)        1500        pitchangle[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_52 (Embedding)        (None, 1, 50)        78350       genspeed[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_53 (Embedding)        (None, 1, 50)        3050        temp[0][0]                       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_54 (Embedding)        (None, 1, 50)        100         turbine[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_6 (Concatenate)     (None, 1, 350)       0           embedding_48[0][0]               
                                                                 embedding_49[0][0]               
                                                                 embedding_50[0][0]               
                                                                 embedding_51[0][0]               
                                                                 embedding_52[0][0]               
                                                                 embedding_53[0][0]               
                                                                 embedding_54[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
spatial_dropout1d_3 (SpatialDro (None, 1, 350)       0           concatenate_6[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_17 (Flatten)            (None, 350)          0           spatial_dropout1d_3[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_24 (Dense)                (None, 1024)         359424      flatten_17[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_18 (Dropout)            (None, 1024)         0           dense_24[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_25 (Dense)                (None, 256)          262400      dropout_18[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_19 (Dropout)            (None, 256)          0           dense_25[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_26 (Dense)                (None, 1)            257         dropout_19[0][0]                 
==================================================================================================
Total params: 817,981
Trainable params: 817,981
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

While trying to fit the model I am getting following error.

```
InvalidArgumentError: indices[19577,0] = -3 is not in [0, 2160)
     [[Node: embedding_50/GatherV2 = GatherV2[Taxis=DT_INT32, Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@training_3/Adam/gradients/embedding_50/GatherV2_grad/Reshape"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](embedding_50/embeddings/read, embedding_50/Cast, embedding_48/GatherV2/axis)]]
```

What is the cause of this error.? How to fix this.?

My input data contains negative values is that the problem.? Is there a way to incorporate negative values then.?

Comment: Is this relevant? https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2734#issuecomment-281926707

Comment: I have gone through the link. But I could find there `I didn't used the same data set for predicting and training. That was my solution.` I am not using a same dataset for training and predicting. Actually the training never starts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your use of Embedding makes no sense, you say that your inputs have negative values. If you look at the [documentation for Embedding](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/) it says:

> Turns positive integers (indexes) into dense vectors of fixed size.
>   eg. [[4], [20]] -> [[0.25, 0.1], [0.6, -0.2]]

This makes me feel that your inputs are not positive integers, meaning that using embedding on those inputs makes no sense. Embedding is used for language modeling for example, to transform word indices into vectors, and it should work with any kind of **positive integer** inputs, but not with general inputs.

Comment: I was trying to make something like this https://www.kaggle.com/alexanderkireev/deep-learning-support-9663